# THREE JS Collada performance issue

Tags: javascript, three.js, collada

I have the following code which load a collada model to THREE.js, i clone it to 100 one then add each one to the scene, everything is ok but after loading the performance become very bad although they are only 100 objects and i plan load about 10000 objects for about 100 model.

```
    var loader=new THREE.ColladaLoader();
loader.options.convertUpAxis = true;
var gc=new THREE.Object3D();
loader.load("resources/models/274.dae",function(collada){
    for(var i=0;i<100;i++){
        var c=collada.scene.clone();
        c.position.set(i,0,i*Math.random());
        scene.add(c);
    }
},function(xhr){
    var percentComplete = xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100;
    document.getElementById("sload").innerHTML="Scene, Mountain Downloaded: "+ Math.round(percentComplete, 2) + '%';
});
```

what should i do for best performance?

Comment: Not a THREEJS expert but couldn't the problem be that you're adding the whole collada scene and not just the model you need? ( collada.scene.clone(); ) ?

Comment: the collada scene containing only one model "a tree" which is 40 KB

Comment: I think it looks like it contains only a tree but it contains a lot of information which is not needed and could mess it up a bit. I think there's a collada model loader. Try to understand how it's done here: http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_collada  The script: http://threejs.org/examples/js/loaders/ColladaLoader.js

Comment: I am using SketchUp to export models to dae format, i converted to obj model then used OBJMTLLoader the performance become slightly better but still slow then i downloaded a obj model from clara.io then loaded it 10000 times (not 100) the result very smooth moving camera !! so the problem in SketchUp exported files.

Comment: Find a way to import ONLY what you need. I remember I had a similar problem once and ended up parsing an obj file, reading all the vertexes and faces and create a mesh from those vertices. That might not be the best way to go but at least you're sure you load only the mesh

Comment: Another thing worth a shot is to import the model into blender and export it from there

Comment: Also, be sure to merge the geometries into one mesh in a tool like Blender. To do that, follow the instructions in this link http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7735/how-to-merge-all-scene-geometry-into-a-single-mesh. I had an object with 430 nodes with horrible performance. As soon as I merged it into a single mesh, it was imported into threejs as a single mesh object and the performance was great.